# Объясните что происходит в метадах findViewById и findViewTraversal

Tags: java, android

Охота понять что конкретно происходит в этих методах. Заходим в класс View и видим вот что:

```
@Nullable
public final <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == NO_ID) {
        return null;
    }
    return findViewTraversal(id);
}
/**
 * @param id the id of the view to be found
 * @return the view of the specified id, null if cannot be found
 * @hide
 */
protected <T extends View> T findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return (T) this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

По простому я знаю объяснение - findviewbyId ищет view по id, которое мы указали в xml разметке. Так что конкретно здесь происходит?

Comment: @woesss ну вот  Т - это что?mID - это ID Т?

Comment: T это тип возвращаемого значения. Почитайте про Generic, Wildcards и PECS в java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это методы класс View. findViewById валидирует аргумент id, при успешной валидации вызывается метод findViewTraversal (**он отвечает за поиск внутри View(себя)**). Он проверяет принадлежит ли ему искомый id.

Чтоб понять зачем вообще так сделано нужно посмотреть еще класс ViewGroup extend View (он прямой потомок View). Это базовый класс для всех видов контейнеров: LinerLayout, RelativeLayout и тд. Он переопределяет findViewTraversal (**он отвечает за поиск внутри ViewGroup (себя)**). В методе findViewTraversal мы берем каждую View и спрашиваем ее, принадлежит ли ей искомый id через методы которые описаны в вашем вопросе.

```
/**
 * {@hide}
 */
@Override
protected <T extends View> T findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return (T) this;
    }
    final View[] where = mChildren;
    final int len = mChildrenCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        View v = where[i];
        if ((v.mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_IS_ROOT_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
            v = v.findViewById(id);
            if (v != null) {
                return (T) v;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Таким образом мы можем искать элементы по айди в любых видах представления (View).

Comment: С ViewGroup в целом понятно, но конкретно с приведенным мной кодом - я не понимаю.

Comment: Что не понятно? Внутри класса View есть два этих метода, они нужны чтоб узнать равен ли какой-то  id переданный нами в метод view. findViewById(123) - id этого конкретного view.

Comment: т.е. сперва вызывается ViewGroup.findViewbyId() потом ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(), а тот в свою очередь вызывает view.findViewbyId() , так?

Comment: Да, для всех вью которые в него входит

Comment: Всем известно что findViewbyId() это "тяжелая" операция. А что же конкретно в коде требует много ресурсов?Ведь если мы указываем тип view в скобках перед findViewbyId(), то зачастую и перебирать особо много элементов и не приходится.

Comment: Тип вью вообще ни как не относится к алгоритму поиска. Поиск идет по айди, а не по типу. Каст происходит непосредственно когда вью найдена. Я привел код в котором все это видно.

Comment: Ну а все же, что "тяжелого" в findViewbyId()?

Comment: То что нужно обойти всю иерархию вью чтоб найти нужную, и чем больше вложенность и количество вью тем больше времени это может занять.